# S3 Batch operations fails when key has '++' symbol

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using S3 Batch operations to copy some files between buckets in different regions.

Here is my manifest:

```
test-input-bucket,preview++.png
test-input-bucket,preview.png
```

`preview.png` copies just fine, but `preview++.png` doesn't. It gives this error in the report output:

```
test-input-bucket,preview++.png,,failed,200,PermanentFailure,PermanentFailure: 404: Not Found
```

The key definitely exists, so I tried to escape the +'s in the manifest like so:

```
test-input-bucket,preview\+\+.png
```

but no luck (same issue). Is there a way for me to fix this without renaming the file?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-create-job.html#specify-batchjob-manifest, the keys have to be url-encoded, so the key would have to be encoded as `preview%2B%2B.png`